# How can I access the Active Time (%) of my c-drive?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, monitor, hard-drive

If you open up resource monitor (win7) under Storage it has a property called "Active Time (%)"  I want to find out what the active time percentages is on each of my HDD using C#.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LogicalDisk|PhysicalDisk\% Disk Time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc938959.aspx)

> Reports the percentage of time that the selected disk drive is busy
>   servicing read or write requests. Because this counters data can span
>   more than one sample, and consequently overstate disk utilization,
>   compare this value against % Idle Time for a more accurate picture.

[LogicalDisk|PhysicalDisk\% Disk Write Time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc938959.aspx)

> Reports the percentage of time that the selected disk drive is busy
>   servicing write requests.

[LogicalDisk|PhysicalDisk\% Disk Read Time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc938959.aspx)

> Reports the percentage of time that the selected disk drive is busy
>   servicing read requests.

Below are two good examples.

[An Introduction To Performance Counters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx)

[Using Performance Counters in C#](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial211_Using-Performance-Counters-in-Csharp.html)

Answer (score 4):

The LogicalDisk performance counter object has a "% Idle Time" counter: maybe one hundred minus this?

Performance counters can be read via WMI or more directly via [`System.Diagnostics.PerforanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx), the [`NextValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx) method is used to get each sample (and the linked documentation contains a sample).

Comment: I have done some tests and it seems that 100 - % Idle Time is much better to show how active the disc is than % Disk Time

Answer (score 2):

You need to access `PerformanceCounterType.CounterTimerInverse` - for samples see MSDN at
[performancecountertype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountertype.aspx) and [performancecounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx).